# Why does mount --bind in linux require root privileges?

Tags: linux, kernel, bind, root, mount

Even if you have all permissions for mount source/destination it requires root, why?

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can use [`bindfs`](http://bindfs.org) to do the same thing as with `mount --bind` but with the added bonus that `bindfs` won't require you root privileges, because it is a [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem.

Answer (score 4):

That's simply because the underlying system call (see 'man 2 mount') requires CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability no matter what the mount options are.

Allowing a user to perform mount calls would probably be rather tricky regarding security.

If you want to allow certain mount operations you can use a tool like sudo by writing appropriate rules for it.

Comment: But is there any idea behind this behaviour? Mount for users is extremely usefull for overriding files used by applications as replacement for painfull backuping -> copying -> restoring.

Comment: Well I can't really tell you what the idea of the people that designed this was. I think many features are useful but still restricted to root, because they're just as dangerous as they're useful. Still it doesn't mean you can't use that. It's just a question of configuration.